# Dos input type="text" y uno debe ser rellenado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo dos input text y uno de los dos debe ser obligatorio, da igual el que se cumplimente, mientras que el otro debe quedar como readonly para evitar que se escriba en los dos.

```
<input type="text" name="carne">
<input type="text" name="pescado">
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo en jquery o javascript?

Gracias.

Comment: Echa un vistazo al evento `onchange` para controlar cuando cambia el texto en los input (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp, https://api.jquery.com/change/), y a la función de jquery `prop` para cambiar propiedades de un elemento (https://api.jquery.com/prop/) Ojo con readonly porque tendrás que poner la o en mayúscula: `$("#pescado").prop('readOnly', true);` Intenta hacerlo tú y si te atascas pega el código y vemos como lo arreglamos.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas soluciona tu pregunta, recuerda aceptarla para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes. En caso contrario, déjanos tus comentarios para ver de que manera se pueden mejorar.

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo hice de esta manera espero te sirva.

Solo utilice el evento onchange para cambiar los inputs automáticos y cambiarle el atributo readonly dependiendo cual se haya llenado primero.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Carne:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtN1" onchange="carne(this.value)" />
    <br /><br />
    <label>Pescado</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtN2" onchange="pescado(this.value)" />
    <br /><br />
  </body>
  <script>
    function carne(value) {
      if (value > 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtN2").readOnly = true;
      }
    }

    function pescado(value) {
      if (value > 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtN1").readOnly = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Si requieres probar con el segundo input y que el primero sea readonly tendrás que ejecutar de nuevo ya que no especificaste si habrá un botón de reset.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, debes agregas un `class` o un `id` para acceder fácilmente al `input`.

A los dos `input` les asignas el atributo `required` en el `html`.

Luego, desde `jQuery`, al hacer click en cualquiera de los `input`, eliminas el atributo `required` del otro y le agregas el atributo `readonly`

```js
//Al hacer click en el input carne
$('#carne').click(function(){
  //elimino el atributo required y agrego el atributo readonly de pescado
  $('#pescado').removeAttr('required').attr('readonly','readonly');
})

//Al hacer click en el input pescado
$('#pescado').click(function(){
//elimino el atributo required y agrego el atributo readonly de carne
  $('#carne').removeAttr('required').attr('readonly','readonly');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="carne" id="carne" required>
<input type="text" name="pescado" id="pescado" required>
```

Verifica en la consola de chrome que los atributos son cambiados debidamente al hacer click en cualquiera de los `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes capturar los eventos keypress sobre los inputs. Yo he puesto los nombres de los dos inputs, pero también lo podrías hacer poniendo la misma class en los dos inputs.
Luego hay que habilitar o deshabilitar el input dependiendo el valor del contrario.

```
$('input[name="carne"], input[name="pescado"]').keypress(function(){

    $('input[name="carne"]').prop('disabled', $('input[name="pescado"]').val().length);
    $('input[name="pescado"]').prop('disabled', $('input[name="carne"]').val().length);

});
```